# can't upload JSON file to parse.com - file format error

Tags: json, parse-platform

I'm trying to import a json file to Parse but I keep getting the following error:

file should should have the following format

```
{ "results": [ {...}, ... ]}
```

I'm using import data -> custom

This is the json file:

```
[{"id":"1","phone":"000"}, {"id":"2","phone":"111"}]
```

JSLint says its good.

What I'm missing here?

Thanks,
Avi

Comment: Well you aren't sticking to their structure they just asked you for.. change it to: `{ "results": [{"id":"1","phone":"000"}, {"id":"2","phone":"111"}]}`...

Comment: I tried it many items but I thought that the "results" string is just a recommendation for the name of the collection. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data have different format. They say you should use:

```
{ "results": [ … ] }
```

But you omit the outer object and send only the array. Send this instead:

```
{ "results": [{"id":"1","phone":"000"}, {"id":"2","phone":"111"}] }
```

JSLint only checks JSON syntax, not that you use correct scheme (how the values are organized and what they mean).

Comment: I tried it many items but I thought that the "results" string is just a recommendation for the name of the collection. thanks